# How to sample a color within an image

Tags: objective-c, ios, colors, uiimage

I'm trying to implement some sort of eyedropper that can sample pixel color in an image and save that as an RGB or CMYK color value. Ideally it would be draggable, and perhaps function something like the magnifying loop does. If anyone can point me in the direction of code or a component that would help allot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the function NSReadPixel which gives you the color of the passed in point

Comment: NSReadPixel is not available in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

To get a pixel color you can use a category on UIView: https://github.com/ivanzoid/ikit/tree/master/UIView%2BColorOfPoint

For draggabel behaviour you should use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.